# SipDemo in Android 2.3

Tags: android, sip

I just follow [this](http://xilard.hu/) to enable SIP in Android 2.3 emulator.
I can use Sipdriod in G1 to get call from emulator, but the emulator can't get call from  G1.

What's problem with this? 
Or is any other way to test new SIP API in emulators?

Edited:
I just redir add udp:5060:5060 in my emulator, but still can't work.

Comment: Please choose your anwser.

Answer (score 1):

you must run an emulator with an SDK of 2.3 as documented but it ios recommended that you can test only on an actual handset with OS version 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because Sipdroid and fring do not use the native SIP API(they probably have their own sip stack), so that's why it worked for you with Sipdroid and not with the android sip api.

And as you probably know, you will not be able to test the android SIP API in a AVD(emulator).

As stated on the demo sip sample [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html#testing):

> To test SIP applications, you need the
>   following:
>
> A mobile device that is running
>   Android 2.3 or higher. 
> SIP runs over
>   wireless, so you must test on an
>   actual device. **Testing on AVD won't
>   work.** 
> A SIP account. There are many
>   different SIP providers that offer SIP
>   accounts. 
> If you are placing a call,
>   it must also be to a valid SIP
>   account.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here related with multicast. Receiving UDP Multicast datagrams was not supported by the Android emulator. The emulator will send (multicast) UDP datagrams, however.

Thats why outgoing works and incoming fails.